# Syntax error at else, delete this token

Tags: java, if-statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Menu {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int choice, quantity;
        double price = 0;  
        double studentprice = 0;
        double totalamt = 0;
        String option,student;
        char option1, studentChar;

        do{

        System.out.println("menu");
        System.out.println("====");

        System.out.println("1. Hamburger");
        System.out.println("2. CheeseBurger");
        System.out.println("3. FrenchFries");
        System.out.println("4. SoftDrinks");

        System.out.print("Enter your choice (1,2,3 or 4):");
        choice = sc.nextInt();

        if(choice ==1)
            price = 1.5;
        else if (choice ==2)
            price = 2;
        else if (choice ==3)
            price = 2.4;
        else if (choice ==4)
        price= 1.95;

        System.out.print("Enter the quantity of your order:");
        quantity = sc.nextInt();

        totalamt += price * quantity ;
        sc.nextLine();


        System.out.print("Do you want to continue? (yes/no)?");
        option = sc.next();
        option1 = option.charAt(0);

        System.out.println("");

        }

        while(option1 == 'y');
        System.out.print("Are you a student? (yes/no?)");
        student = sc.next();
        studentChar = student.charAt(0);

        if(studentChar == 'y')
        studentprice = totalamt * 0.9;
        System.out.print("$ " + studentprice + " is the price you have to pay " );

        **else**(studentChar == 'n')
        studentprice = price;
        System.out.print("$ " + price + " is the price you have to pay " ); 
    }


}`
```

There is an error on the last else. It says syntax error at else, delete this token. Please help! When i add do while, it prints zero. -Filler Filler Filler Filler Filler Filler-

Thankyou! :)

Comment: You cannot have () after 'else'. Only after 'if'. I suppose that the ** are not in the real code you are trying to compile. And "while(option1 == 'y');" seems pointless to me (can it even run?)

Comment: no those are actually what i want to point out

Comment: Yes i can run while(option1 == 'y') i've tried deleting the () behind the else. It keeps saying its a syntax error whenever i type a else

Answer (score 2):

Syntax is not proper. you should use bracket when you have more than one statement under you `if-block`, Otherwise only first statement would be treated within `if-block` & other statement would not be part of `if-block`.

And In this case `else` statement is there without `if` as `if-block` finished after `studentprice = totalamt * 0.9;` line.

```
if(studentChar == 'y'){
    studentprice = totalamt * 0.9;
    System.out.print("$ " + studentprice + " is the price you have to pay " );
}else(studentChar == 'n'){
    studentprice = price;
    System.out.print("$ " + price + " is the price you have to pay " ); 

}
```

Comment: Your loop Would only exit if 'Y' is pressed, I don't think this is intended.

Comment: you may be write but that is out of scope, I can see there are certain other changes which is required on this piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Error is here in the line  it should be **else if**

```
  **else**(studentChar == 'n')
studentprice = price;
```

it should be

```
if(studentChar == 'y'){
        studentprice = totalamt * 0.9;
        System.out.print("$ " + studentprice + " is the price you have to pay " );
        }
        else if(studentChar == 'n'){
        studentprice = price;
        System.out.print("$ " + price + " is the price you have to pay " ); 
        }else{


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
studentChar = 0;
while(studentChar  != 'y' && studentChar  != 'n')
{
    System.out.print("Are you a student? (yes/no?)");
    student = sc.next();
    studentChar = student.charAt(0);
}

    if(studentChar == 'y')
    {
        studentprice = totalamt * 0.9;
        System.out.print("$ " + studentprice + " is the price you have to pay " );
    }
    else if(studentChar == 'n')
    {
        studentprice = price;
        System.out.print("$ " + price + " is the price you have to pay " ); 
    }
```

Comment: Test it. If the user enters something invalid like 'x' it will continue.

Comment: where have u changed your option1... then

Answer (score 0):

I am confused with your code. How were you able to compile this code with

> `else(studentChar == 'n')`

**You can not check condition with else, you have to use if for that**

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu {

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice, quantity;
    double price = 0;
    double studentprice = 0;
    double totalamt = 0;
    String option,student;
    char option1, studentChar;

    do{

        System.out.println("menu");
        System.out.println("====");

        System.out.println("1. Hamburger");
        System.out.println("2. CheeseBurger");
        System.out.println("3. FrenchFries");
        System.out.println("4. SoftDrinks");

        System.out.print("Enter your choice (1,2,3 or 4):");
        choice = sc.nextInt();

        if(choice ==1)
            price = 1.5;
        else if (choice ==2)
            price = 2;
        else if (choice ==3)
            price = 2.4;
        else if (choice ==4)
            price= 1.95;

        System.out.print("Enter the quantity of your order:");
        quantity = sc.nextInt();

        totalamt += price * quantity ;
        sc.nextLine();


        System.out.print("Do you want to continue? (yes/no)?");
        option = sc.next();
        option1 = option.charAt(0);

        System.out.println("");

    }

    while(option1 == 'y');
    System.out.print("Are you a student? (yes/no?)");
    student = sc.next();
    studentChar = student.charAt(0);

    if(studentChar == 'y')
    {
        studentprice = totalamt * 0.9;
        System.out.print("$ " + studentprice + " is the price you have to pay " );
    }
   else if(studentChar == 'n')
   {
       studentprice = price;
       System.out.print("$ " + studentprice + " is the price you have to pay " );

   }
}
}
```

This will work now

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
do
{
    System.out.print("Are you a student? (yes/no?)");
    student = sc.next();
    studentChar = student.charAt(0);
} while(studentChar != 'y' && studentChar != 'n');

if(studentChar == 'y')
{
  //do something here
 }
 else if(studentChar == 'n')
 {
  //other statement
  }
```