# Syntax error on token "else", delete this token

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

Im getting Syntax error can someone please tell me whats wrong.

Console text:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Syntax error on token "else", delete this token
    at gg.main(gg.java:23)
```

Code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;


public class gg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


String browser = "Chrome";

WebDriver driver = null;

if(browser.equals("Mozilla"))
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

else if(browser.equals("Chrome"))
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    else if(browser.equals("IE"))
        System.setProperty("webdriver.IE.driver", "C:\\Users\\Ryuk~\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.43.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();


    driver.get("https://gmail.com");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());





    }

}
```

Comment: This is the reason why I shout to use curly braces. Please try to arrange them using `{}`. You'll find your answer.

Comment: please use opening and closing braces {}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error at else, delete this token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357758/syntax-error-at-else-delete-this-token)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is missing braces ( that's these: `{}` BTW). It's ok if your if statement involves only a single line, however i'd advise to use them anyway for readability.

Overall, your code should look similar to:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;


public class gg {

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {


     String browser = "Chrome";

     WebDriver driver = null;

     if(browser.equals("Mozilla"))
     {
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     }
     else 
     {
         if(browser.equals("Chrome"))
         {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
         }
         else
         {
            if(browser.equals("IE"))
            {
               System.setProperty("webdriver.IE.driver", "C:\\Users\\Ryuk~\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.43.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
               driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            }
         }
      }
      if(driver !null)
      {
         driver.get("https://gmail.com");
         System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
      }
   }
}
```

I also added a small piece of validation so as to check if the driver isn't null (i.e. has been assigned first), before printing it.

I also hope you have a method for `getTitle()` otherwise there could be issues there as well.

---

## Now,

---

1) That *should solve your problem.

2) I (personally) think it is easier to read.

3) I hope you've learnt the importance of `{}` s in your code.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot `{}`
Do it in this way:

```
if(browser.equals("Mozilla"))
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

else if(browser.equals("Chrome")){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}else if(browser.equals("IE")){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.IE.driver", "C:\\Users\\Ryuk~\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.43.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
}
driver.get("https://gmail.com");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

use if without `{}` is only possible if you have only one line, like your first part

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you forgot to enclose the statements of if, elseif and else into braces {}.
I personally prefer using braces for each if, ... even if it has just one statement. Btw. it makes code more readable too ;)

This should work:

```
if(browser.equals("Mozilla")) {
  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
} else if(browser.equals("Chrome")) {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
} else if(browser.equals("IE")) {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.IE.driver", "C:\\Users\\Ryuk~\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.43.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
  driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
}

driver.get("https://gmail.com");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Answer (score 0):

if else block without curly braces only accept one instruction in each block. Besides, a good indentation is the base of a readable code, it will avoid you some trouble like that.